# How can I enable "Make a copy" in Drive UI

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a custom application with custom file types integrating into Drive using the drive API presented in the Google developer console.

File creation works fine, but the context menu for the new files doesn't include the "Make a copy" option like it does for native Google Doc types. Is it possible to get this for custom applications/file types?

The developer console lets you specify URLs for other specific operations like Open URL and New URL (File creation).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you required to use Drive UI? There's a 'copy' method in the [`Files`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy) resource that would be helpful in your case. You can use this alongside AppScript (if this is what you're using) when creating a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus?hl=en)

Comment: @adjuremods Yeah I'm trying to get the copy option to show up in the Drive  UI context menu.